# Down single connection

Tags: tcp

There are many connections to the external interface(s) on the specified port
e.g.

```
![netstat |grep 1521][1]

tcp….1540….…0 172.17.40.33:36791……..172.17.40.90:1521…….…..ESTABLISHED 
tcp….1540….…0 172.17.40.33:36793……..172.17.40.90:1521…….…..ESTABLISHED 
tcp….1540….…0 172.17.40.33:36795……..172.17.40.90:1521…….…..ESTABLISHED 
tcp….1540….…0 172.17.40.33:36799……..172.17.40.90:1521…….…..ESTABLISHED 
tcp….1540….…0 172.17.40.33:36801……..172.17.40.90:1521…….…..ESTABLISHED 
tcp….1540….…0 172.17.40.33:36803……..172.17.40.90:1521…….…..ESTABLISHED 
tcp….1540….…0 172.17.40.33:36805……..172.17.40.90:1521…….…..ESTABLISHED 
tcp….1540….…0 172.17.40.33:36807……..172.17.40.90:1521…….…..ESTABLISHED
```

**Question**: How to down single connection without touching the rest of the connections.

Comment: By design, the only reliable way is to either terminate the process that opened the port or somehow get the process that opened the port to close the port.

Comment: 1521 sounds like oracle default tcp port, maybe you sould try from oracle ? e. g. `lsnrctl status`

Comment: 1521 is example only from current linux unit. Actually for **APNs** (Apple Push Notification) with default a server port 2195. According to spec count of similar connections in the same time is 15. I should to down only one connection from the list.

Answer (score 3):

Typically the connection can only be closed by either killing the process or if the process explicitly closes the connection.

As you might find in other search results, the `tcpkill` utility found in this package: http://monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/ can "close" a particular connection.  However, it is doing so rather violently.

The utility listens for traffic associated with that connection (via libpcap) and then sends TCP RST packets in a loop in an attempt to send 1 with the correct sequence number.

Depending on the application, it might be possible to attach to the process with a debugger (or, depending on the language, via some other method) and use knowledge of the programs internals to arrange for the connection to be closed.

Comment: 'tcpkill' is working with specified port. So with such command I can close all connection to port (in my case 2195). Or I am wrong?